# conv2d function in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, convolution

I'm trying to use the function [torch.conv2d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#id22) from Pytorch but can't get a result I understand...

Here is a simple example where the kernel (`filt`) is the same size as the input (`im`) to explain what I'm looking for.

```
import pytorch

filt = torch.rand(3, 3)
im = torch.rand(3, 3)
```

*I want to compute a simple convolution with no padding*, so the result should be a scalar (i.e. a 1x1 tensor).

I tried this with `conv2d`:

```
# I have to convert image and kernel to 4 dimensions tensors to use conv2d
im_torch = im.reshape((im_height, filt_height, 1, 1))
filt_torch = filt.reshape((filt_height, im_height, 1, 1))
out = torch.nn.functional.conv2d(im_torch, filt_torch, stride=1, padding=0)
print(out)
```

But the result is not what I expected:

```
tensor([[[[0.6067]], [[0.3564]], [[0.5397]]],
    [[[0.2557]], [[0.0493]], [[0.2562]]],
    [[[0.6067]], [[0.3564]], [[0.5397]]]])
```

To give an idea of what I'd like, I want to reproduce scipy `convolve2d` behavior:

```
import scipy.signal
out_scipy = scipy.signal.convolve2d(im.detach().numpy(), filt.detach().numpy(), 'valid')
print(out_scipy)
```

which prints:

```
array([[1.195723]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 8):

The tensor shape of your input and the filter should be:

*`(batch, dim_ch, width, height)`*

and NOT:

*`(width, height, 1, 1)`*

e.g.

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
x = torch.randn(1,1,4,4);
y = torch.randn(1,1,4,4);
z = F.conv2d(x,y);
```

Output shape of `z`:

```
torch.Size([1,1,1,1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I didn't find the exact answer to my question (i.e. how to use conv2d) but I found another way to do it.

First of all, I learned that I'm looking for is called a *valid* cross-correlation and it is actually the operation implemented by the `[Conv2d][1]` class.

Hence my solution uses the `Conv2d` class instead of the `conv2d` function.

```
import pytorch

img = torch.rand(3, 3)

model = torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=1, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=1, padding=0, bias=False)

res = conv_mdl(img)
print(res.shape)
```

Which prints the scalar I wanted:

```
torch.Size([1, 1, 1, 1])
```

PS: I also checked that the result is the right one, not just the dimension.